# Summing variables of CSV for d3.js

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

Suppose I have this CSV file:

```
USA;Apple;Phone;
EU;Apple;Computer;
USA;Samsung;Computer;
USA;Apple;Phone;
EU;Samsung;Computer;
```

I'd like to use the data to render a chart with d3.js and display multiple bar charts with this result:

- Sum of Apple in USA: 2
- Sum of Computer in EU: 2
- Sum of Phone: 2

I currently have this:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  d3.csv("node_data.csv", function(error, data) {
  // Convert strings to numbers.
    data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.people = +d.country;
    d.year = +d.object;
    d.age = +d.brand;
  });
  var people = d.value(data, function(d) { return d.object; });
  document.getElementById('valeur').innerHTML = people;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Data seems to be separated through `semi-colon` and there's no numbers available too. Please provide us correct sample data. Also provide a fiddle with code you've tried with.

Comment: You probably want nesting for this, see [this tutorial](http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/).